# How to do eager fetching of related data using F# SQLProvider with Postgres?

Tags: f#, graphql, f#-data

I am using F# [SQLProvider](https://fsprojects.github.io/SQLProvider/) with F# [GraphQL](https://fsprojects.github.io/FSharp.Data.GraphQL/). To address classic N+1 select problem with GraphQL nested resolvers, I need to early fetch related/relational/nested data in top-level GraphQL resolver. The basic idea is to recursively walk the GraphQL request AST and build the SQL query with joins. It is very similar to the idea of [almightly root resolver](https://blog.smartive.ch/advanced-graphql-patterns-the-almighty-root-resolver-f284872397cb)

So far, I can dynamically build the nested query but SQLProvider still loads the fresh data when nested field is accessed by the means of foreign key.

How can I address this problem with SQLProvider to avoid N+1 select?